# A very simple ode formation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $$ \sin 2u + \sin v   = 0 ; \, a^2 2u '' +  \sin 2u   = 0;\ $$

are given ( primes with respect to time,  $a$ is a constant),

then,  is $$ v'' + \sin v /a^2 = 0 $$  or, $$  v'' - \sin v /a^2 =0?  $$  or both?

Comment: How did it become $v''$? What happened to the $2u''$?

Comment: Eliminate $u$ from first two, leaving only $v$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin 2u  = -\sin v \implies 2u = \sin^{-1}-\sin v 
$$
Using $\sin (-x) =-\sin x$ leads to 
$$
2u = \sin^{-1}\sin(-v) = -v
$$
So you can see that 
$$
u'' = -\frac{1}{2}v''
$$
This means the ode becomes
$$
-a^2v''  -\sin v = 0
$$